# How to Clear Interval when Using Set Interval in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, refresh, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a jquery plugin that autofreshes the page every 5 mins.

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.refreshPage = function() {

    setInterval(function() {
      function x();
    }, 300);
  };
})(jQuery);
```

but the problem is that I want it to reset the timer when a certain function runs, I've read about clearInterval, but I'm not sure how to implement that here. To be more specific, I want function x to clear the interval everytime it runs.

**Follow up question:**

How do I call clearInterval on a function on another file given the current structure of my plugin? Sorry noob here. Thanks!

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

My plugin now looks like this

```
(function($) {
  var refresh_timer;
  $.fn.refreshPage = function() {

    refresh_timer = setInterval(function() {
      function x();
    }, 300);
  };
  $.fn.reFreshPage.resetTimer = function() {
    clearInterval(refresh_timer);
})(jQuery);
```

And I call:

```
$.fn.reFreshPage.resetTimer
```

to reset the intervals, but the problem is that it breaks the setInterval and no longer refreshes the page after the timer has been reset. Am I missing something here?

Comment: clearInterval doesn't reset the interval timer - it stops it entirely.  If you want to "restart" it, you would have to clear the current interval and then start a new interval.  Also, I don't know what you're doing with "reFreshPage", but if you're actually refreshing the page (e.g. loading a new page), then all your current javascript stops and gets reinitialized by the new page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to remember the return value from the original call to setInterval and you can then pass that to clearInterval in order to stop the timer.

```
var timer = setInterval(...);
clearInterval(timer);
```

Sometimes, when you want more control, it's easier to not use `setInterval()`, but to use `setTimeout()` and just repeatedly call `setTimeout()` on each successive timer until you want it to stop.  This technique also makes it easier to vary the timer interval if desired.

Comment: thanks! but one more question..how do I call the clearInterval on another function, because I am planning to call it on function x, w/c is in another file, sorry newbie here..

Comment: Same way, just make sure to assign your interval to a var like jfriend00 did, and make sure that var is accessible to the function that will handle the clearing.